# Crystal Reports load reportDocument failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I use crystal reports on vs 2010 c#, and i create pdf files using rpt documents of CR.

I put this code on windows service,my code works normally for 30 - 40 times but then memory is rising per +5 +7 each progress.

Last i get error like this: load file is failed !

My code: (i think i dispose/close conn but how)

```
     private void ReportLogin(ReportDocument crDoc, string Database, string Server, string UserID, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Server;
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Database;
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = UserID;
            crConnectionInfo.Password = Password;

            crDatabase = crDoc.Database;
            crTables = crDatabase.Tables;

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
            {
                crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            throw x;
        }
    }

    private void _CrystalReport(string RptFilePath)
    {

        reportDocument = LoadDoc(RptFilePath);

        RptParamsWithType = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (reportDocument.ParameterFields.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ParameterField pField in reportDocument.ParameterFields)
            {
                RptParamsWithType.Add(pField.Name,              pField.ParameterValueType.ToString().Replace("Parameter", ""));
            }
        }
    }
```

Load Function:

```
    private ReportDocument LoadDoc(string RptFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            reportDocument.Load(RptFilePath);

            return reportDocument;

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            throw x;
        }

    }
```

My function that last called is create pdf:

```
     public MemoryStream asPdf
    {
        get
        {
            using (TempMemoryStream = (MemoryStream)reportDocument.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat))
            {
                return TempMemoryStream;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks Advice, help me plz

Comment: this is the part in your code where you set the database login, not the part where you load the report (and your error is "load file is failed!"). you might show the right portion of your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i converted my code like this sample and it works!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using CrystalDecisions;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

namespace Test.Utilities
{
   public class ReportFactory
   {
       protected static Queue reportQueue = new Queue();

       protected static ReportClass CreateReport(Type reportClass)
      {
        object report = Activator.CreateInstance(reportClass);
        reportQueue.Enqueue(report);
        return (ReportClass)report;
      }

    public static ReportClass GetReport(Type reportClass)
    {
        //75 is my print job limit.
        if (reportQueue.Count > 75) ((ReportClass)reportQueue.Dequeue()).Dispose();
        return CreateReport(reportClass);
    }
  } 
}
```

[Original Link](http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2007/07/17/114008.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```
ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", @"server name", "DB name");
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
```

Hope It helps you.

Comment: If still persist,it might be possible Permission issue.For that please refer That link [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297119/Crystal-Reports-Fix-for-Load-report-failed-error)

Comment: my code is working normally in 2-3 hours.But has memory leak problem

Comment: So Remove your temp files because rpt files are created a copy in temp file folder.

Comment: Press Ctrl+r and type %temp% in Run .Delete all the files in open folder

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void LoadReport()
    {
        doc = new ReportDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("CrSalesReport.rpt"));
        doc.SetDatabaseLogon(AppConfig.ReportServerDSUserName, AppConfig.ReportServerDSPassword, AppConfig.ReportServerDomain, "TexERP", false);

    }
```

Try this code for Database Logon

Comment: i dont use CrystalReportViewer.Its only dll and it returns me pdf stream.