# Crystal Report and errors in Subreports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I created a report with some subreports on it. I use below code to populate the subreports :

```
 ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument();
            rep.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "salonreport.rpt");                rep.Subreports["rptsalesbydaytypecashdetails"].SetDataSource((DataTable)rptsalesbydaytypecashdetailsDataTable1);
```

for above code an error raise : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

another method is

```
 salonreport rep = new salonreport();
                rep.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "salonreport.rpt");       rep.Subreports["rptsalesbydaytypecashdetails"].SetDataSource((DataTable)rptsalesbydaytypecashdetailsDataTable1);
```

for his I get this error : Unable to find the report in the manifest resources. Please build the project, and try again.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437812/crystal-reports-load-reportdocument-failed) something similar

Comment: it's not related to my issue

Answer (score 0):

Give the code below a try. I believe your issue lies in the file path. PLease replace the file path in my code with a valid file path from your system.

```
   public void ReportLoad()    
       {             
         ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();       
         string filePath = "C:\Projects\Application\Report\CrystalReport.rpt";               reportDocument.Load(filePath);
         reportDocument.Load(filePath); 
         crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument; 
         reportDocument.OpenSubreport("SubReport.rpt")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Server.MapPath(strReportName) to specify path.

```
                ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
                string strRptPath = Server.MapPath(strReportName);
                //Loading Report
                rd.Load(strRptPath);

                // Setting report data source
                if (rptSource != null && rptSource.GetType().ToString() != System.String")
                    rd.SetDataSource(rptSource);
                //setting report source for subreports.
                rd.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(subRptSource1);
                rd.Subreports[1].SetDataSource(subRptSource2);
```